Laravel error handling for authentication system
I want to implement the laravel build in authentication system breeze in my laravel project. But when I clicked on the login or register the css is not working and also it shows a error:
Mix manifest not found at: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel10\public\/mix-manifest.json

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

Please help me to solve the error. I am using the laravel 10 and the php version is 8.1.

Did you run npm install and npm run dev after setting up everything?

Yes ..  after running the "npm install and npm run dev"    I got error ....." Vite manifest not found at: C:\xampp\htdocs\breeze\public\build/manifest.json"     and this   "C:\xampp\htdocs\breeze\resources\views\layouts\guest.blade
.php
 
: 15"

try to cancel all npm executed commands, delete directory public/build then rerun npm install and npm run dev (npm run build if in production)

From laravel 9 change asset bundling mix to vite
change from  'mix('css/app.css')' to
 @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])

and then run npm install && npm run dev
source: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/vite
but if you want to use mix then follow this migrate guide  https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-laravel-mix-to-vite

I already did...but vite version conflicts with laravel version 10 and php version 8.1.25  . It does not worked out.

If you have any other solution that why vite conflicts .... I want  to use the laravel breeze authentication system . If I used other authentication pakages then the vite works properly. I dont know why this happened?

what is your breeze version let me know i'll test in my local get back to you
